Как подключить vk api callback?
Как мне правильно подключить callback vk api? По инструкции VK нужно указать адрес на сервер, который примет запрос от VK и вернет нужную строку. Я использую fastapi
Вот код моей функции, который отвечает на запрос от VK
class CallbackRequest(BaseModel):
    type: str
    group_id: int


@app.post('/api/callback/')
async def callback(request: CallbackRequest):
    return 'abcdeg'

При попытке подключения получаю ошибку
Сервер вернул неправильный ответ: "abcdeg"

Строка, которую должен вернуть сервер: abcdeg


Необходимо явно указать тип возвращаемого ответа, чтобы вернуть строку без кавычек.
@app.post('/api/callback/')
async def callback(request: CallbackRequest):
    a = 'abcdeg'
    return Response(content=a, media_type="text/plain")

